# Angular HTTP Observable @Input

Tags: angular, observable, templating

here is my pseudo code:

**service**

```
getData(): Observable<MyData[]>{
  return this.http.get<Data[]>(`https://localhost/api/data`);
}
```

**component:**

```
myData: Data[];
[...]

ngOnInit(){
 this.myService.getData.subscribe( data => {
   this.myData = data;
   console.log(data);
 });
}
```

**Template:**

```
<app-subComponent *ngIf="data" class="cat-row" [data]='{"type": "row", "data": myData}'></app-subComponent>
```

**SubComponent:**

```
@Input() data: any;

ngOnInit(){
 console.log(data);
}
```

**My Problem:** In this scenario, console.log gives me an empty array. 
If I don't pass this data attribute to my subcomponent via input, my first console.log gives me the correct array.

So maybe i miss something if i want to use http, observable, templating and @input in one "row" ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010333/subscribing-to-observable-input

Answer (score 0):

You should implement OnChanges then you can able to detect input when it changes.

1. Import package

   `import {Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges }`
2. Then implements Onchanges

   ```
   export class SubComponent implements OnChanges {
      @Input() data: any;
      constructor() { }
      ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
         if(changes["data"] && this.data){
            // here you get the result
         }
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for your answere but sadly it don't work for me. My console.log inside // here you get the result is an empty array..

Comment: had you check data is return from service not empty

Comment: if i use data in template as parameter its empty if i dont use it as parameter in template its correct

Comment: I have create stackblitz link here and its work as accepted you can check 
 [ https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2jai2 ]

Comment: check these link and let me know if any issue

Comment: i think the problem occure if there is a http request / obserable